# Angular based application is not picking the production environment configuration after production pipeline is successful

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am running into issue with Angular2 project.
On cloud we have a separate App Service each environment.
Client application is written in Angular2 and server side application is written in WebAPI.
Both application are in separate repos and has different playbook.
I have run the prod pipeline for client. Build is success and artifacts has the production environment configuration.
but when I lunch the application it is still pointing to test web api url and unable to login in application due to CORS.

Here is the playbook for client .

---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  roles:

  - role: ansible-role-azure-asp
  - role: ansible-role-azure-app-service
  - role: ansible-role-azure-app-service-bindcertificate

Why the pipeline is not picking production configuration even though artifacts has the correct configuration.
Please help us out with this issue.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know whether my anwser helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to locate the cause of the issue from your description alone. Here are some tips to help you figure out what caused the issue:

1. Check whether your config file is written correctly
2. Try using tools such as Visual Studio to build and publish the client application locally and see if it works.
3. Search the test web api URL in client application code(There are a number of tools that allow you to search all types of files in a folder and make code matches) to see if there are any places where the client appilication URL was incorrectly written as a test web api URL.